# Explanation of bash for loop exclusion results

Tags: bash, shell

The intention is to exclude certain files (having "actors" in the name) from a list of files in a directory. Here we have a directory with 13 jar files:

```bash
12:58:42/mllib $for f in $SCALA_HOME/lib/*.jar; do echo $f; done
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.2/libexec/lib/akka-actors.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.2/libexec/lib/diffutils.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.2/libexec/lib/jline.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.2/libexec/lib/process-0.1.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.2/libexec/lib/scala-actors-migration.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.2/libexec/lib/scala-actors.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.2/libexec/lib/scala-compiler.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.2/libexec/lib/scala-library.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.2/libexec/lib/scala-partest.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.2/libexec/lib/scala-reflect.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.2/libexec/lib/scala-swing.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.2/libexec/lib/scalap.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.2/libexec/lib/typesafe-config.jar
```

The intention is to filter out / exclude the jar files containing the pattern "actor" inside. How to do that?  Here are my attempts at understanding the exclusion pattern (note: exclusions are NOT regex's though they may look similar due to the []):

```bash
a. Specify to exclude files containing "actors" string:
12:58:38/mllib $for f in $SCALA_HOME/lib/*[!actors*].jar; do echo $f; done
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.2/libexec/lib/jline.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.2/libexec/lib/process-0.1.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.2/libexec/lib/scala-actors-migration.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.2/libexec/lib/scala-library.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.2/libexec/lib/scala-swing.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.2/libexec/lib/scalap.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.2/libexec/lib/typesafe-config.jar
```

Hmmm,  it *did* exclude the scala-actors.jar. But.. it also excluded five other jars  and did *not * exclude the scala-actors-migration.jar.

OOC let us try the inverse - i.e. only include the actors pattern.  Since I am unfamiliar with the syntax, let us attempt two different ways:

Try to include files with *actors*.jar :

```bash
12:58:52/mllib $for f in $SCALA_HOME/lib/*[actors*].jar; do echo $f; done
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.2/libexec/lib/akka-actors.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.2/libexec/lib/diffutils.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.2/libexec/lib/scala-actors.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.2/libexec/lib/scala-compiler.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.2/libexec/lib/scala-partest.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.2/libexec/lib/scala-reflect.jar
```

Try to include only files with *actors.jar at the end:

```bash
12:59:07/mllib $for f in $SCALA_HOME/lib/*[actors].jar; do echo $f; done
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.2/libexec/lib/akka-actors.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.2/libexec/lib/diffutils.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.2/libexec/lib/scala-actors.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.2/libexec/lib/scala-compiler.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.2/libexec/lib/scala-partest.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.10.2/libexec/lib/scala-reflect.jar
```

All of these results are not explainable to me without further discussion on how the exclusion really works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to list/remove all files **but** the ones with `"actor"` in their names, you should do the following:

```
echo ${SCALA_HOME}/lib/!(*actor*.jar)
```

The problem with your attempts was rather a metter of syntax: you should use `(...)` instead of `[...]`.

Comment: HI Rubens,  there is a lesser known capability called exclusions: that is what applies here.  Globbing does come into play, but your answer misses the point about using exclusions

Comment: The intention is to EXCLUDE files with actor in the name

Comment: I updated the question to make the intention explicit.

Comment: @javadba Great, just indent the second snippet you wrote.

Comment: ok done, we had simultaneous edit  earlier, have merged your edit now.

Comment: Ah, alright! Hope I have addressed the problem properly in my last edit.

Comment: Yes, it is a different syntax than I had seen but it does work. Thanks!